# Is there a pattern like ^ in vim?

Tags: vim, regex

In Vim normal mode, the `0` command takes you to the first column on the line and `^` takes you to the logical start of line (e.g. the first non-whitespace character). In the regex world, `^` matches the first character on the line, whitespace or not. Does Vim have a pattern that behaves like its '^' command--matching the logical beginning of a line?

Comment: I think ^ in a regex normally matches the start of the line, not the first character. ^. will match the start and then the first character, not the start and then the second character.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no shortcut to match the first non-whitespace character on a line, you have to build the pattern yourself, like:

```
^\s*restofpattern
```

If you don't want to include the whitespace in your match, you have to use a zero-width assertion, like:

```
\(^\s*\)\@<=restofpattern
```

Not exactly pretty, but at least it gets the job done.

Answer (score 9):

To match the first *non*-whitespace character, you'd just use `\S` like you normally do.

---

If you use `^` in a regex in vim, it will match the actual start of the line, even if it contains whitespace.

For instance, this line starts with a space:

```
 <- there's a space there you can't see :)
```

This vim command will remove the leading space:

```
:%s/^ //
```

resulting in the following:

```
<- there's a space there you can't see :)
```

So, the regex will behave as you expect, even if the command doesn't.

Comment: I presume you're going to explain the downvote. This answer, as far as I know, is correct.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but by way of clarification: I was wondering if Vim has an operator to match the first non-whitespace character of the line. The `^` operator (like all sane regex implementations), will match the first character even if it is whitespace.

Comment: Well, how were you expecting to do it normally? Usually in a regex you would use something like `\S` to match the first non-whitespace character.

Comment: `\S` will match *any* non-whitespace character. To put it another way, I'm wondering if Vim has a zero-width shorthand for this: `^\W*\S`.

Comment: I don't even think _regex_ has something like that.

Comment: No engine that I am aware of provides that functionality, but then again--when would you have cared in a general-purpose engine? Vim isn't a general purpose regex engine. It is an editor that has a regex engine so I was wondering if it had any special constructs for something that only matters inside an editor.